# UIScrollView in container view has incorrect frame size

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uikit, xamarin

I have a UIContainerView with Frame = {X=20,Y=88,Width=728,Height=660} and a UIScrollView embedded inside it.

The UIScrollView reports Frame = {X=0,Y=0,Width=768,Height=960} that results in an offset of 40 (the section in gold) in the width when paging the UIScrollView. It results in the following output having paged once to the left:

[image]

However, ContentSizeForViewInPopover reports the expected Frame size = {Width=728, Height=660}. How can I correct the UIScrollView frame to have the correct size?

Here is the code for ViewDidLoad() of the embedded UIViewController:

```
var pages = PageControl.Pages = 2;
Console.WriteLine("ScrollView Frame: {0}", ScrollView.Frame);

for(int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
{
    RectangleF frame
    frame.X = ScrollView.Frame.Width * i; // expected {728 * i} but is {768 * i}
    frame.Y = 0;
    frame.Size = ScrollView.Frame.Size;

    Console.WriteLine("Subview frame: {0}", frame);

    ScrollView.AddSubview(
        new UIView(frame) { 
            Bounds = frame,
            BackgroundColor = GetRandomColor() 
        });
    }

    ScrollView.ContentSize = new SizeF(ScrollView.Frame.Width * pages, ScrollView.Frame.Height);
    Console.WriteLine("ScrollView ContentSize = {0}", ScrollView.ContentSize);
```

Comment: Where in your code is the UIScrollView created? You have to set its Frame (not ContentSize!) to the superview's bounds and give it proper auto resizing settings.

Comment: The UIScrollView is set on a UIView which is placed inside a UIContainerView on a StoryBoard. The UIScrollView is not explicitly created.

Answer (score 4):

call [self.ScrollView layoutIfNeeded];  before this line

```
frame.X = ScrollView.Frame.Width * i; // expected {728 * i} but is {768 * i}
```

it works with me, goodluck

Answer (score 2):

Double check that in `IB` under the parent `UIViewController`, under the Attributes Inspector, Layout section, that the 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' is unchecked. I had a similar issue that tripped me up for awhile and that was all I needed to do to get the proper layout.

Answer (score 1):

In IOS 7.0 
Use self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO; in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score -3):

Try create your UIScrollView in the code, apparently the designer overrides any adjustment you apply in the code.